# Cardview is all going into one card

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am trying to create a card view for a checklist that will be going into a app for school. All of the items in the ArrayList are going into one card and i cant figure out why. I have looked at every tutorial that i can find but no luck. 
Here is the relevant code. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Activity

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.masterListRecView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

theList = new ArrayList<MasterListItem>();

theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item1",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));
theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item2",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));
theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item3",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));
theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item4",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));
theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item5",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));
theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item6",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));
theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item7",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));
theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item8",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));
theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item9",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));
theList.add(new MasterListItem("Test Item10",new Date(),new Date(),"here are some notes",false));

masterListAdapter = new RecViewAdapter(theList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(masterListAdapter);

masterListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

RecycleView Adapter

```
public class RecViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    TextView title;
    TextView dueDate;
    TextView completedDate;
    TextView notes;
    CheckBox completed;
    private ArrayList<MasterListItem> theList;
    //private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public RecViewAdapter(ArrayList<MasterListItem> theList) {
        this.theList = theList;
        //inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.master_list_item,parent,false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        title = holder.title;
        dueDate = holder.dueDate;
        completedDate = holder.completedDate;
        notes = holder.notes;
        completed = holder.completed;

        title.setText(theList.get(position).getTitle());
        dueDate.setText(theList.get(position).getDueDate().toString());
        completedDate.setText(theList.get(position).getCompletedDate().toString());
        notes.setText(theList.get(position).getNotes());
        completed.setChecked(theList.get(position).isCompleted());
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return theList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView title;
        private TextView dueDate;
        private TextView completedDate;
        private TextView notes;
        private CheckBox completed;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            this.title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.masterListTitle);
            this.dueDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.masterListDueDate);
            this.completedDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.masterListCompletedDate);
            this.notes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.masterListNotes);
            this.completed = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.masterListCompleted);
        }
    }



}
```

RecycleView XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="edu.uco.weddingcrashers.hitched.MasterWeddingList">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/addTaskButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/masterListRecView"
        >



    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Card XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/masterListCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!--
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addTaskButton"
    -->


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/masterListTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="test title" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/masterListDueDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="test title" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/masterListCompletedDate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="test title" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/masterListNotes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="test title" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/masterListCompleted"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Completed"
                android:editable="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Once again Thank you so much!

Comment: Post your layout XML files. Are you wrapping recycler view XML file in a cardview as parent element ?

Comment: I am not as far as i can tell.

Comment: android:layout_alignParentStart why is this needed for each cardview ?

Comment: And card view's parent linear layout is not needed..

Comment: Please remove layout gravity and layout below attributes also from card view

Comment: ok i remove all of those and im still getting the same issue ill update the code above

Comment: nope they are removed see above

Comment: did u really want your textview's to spawn "match_parent" ? Make them wrap_content if its relevant for you

Comment: @Ramesh, your comments are irrelevant to his issue.. Instead of assigning your `viewholder` fields to a `TextView` in `OnBindViewHolder` try just writing `holder.title.setText()`

Comment: @Pztar i changed it over to that form but it is still doing that same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add divider between your `RecyclerView` item. Adding divider and decoration to RecyclerView is different from other list views. You can achieve this by this answer:

Unlike ListView, the RecyclerView class has no divider-related parameters. Instead, you need to extend [ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html), a RecyclerView's inner class:

> An ItemDecoration allows the application to add a special drawing and
>   layout offset to specific item views from the adapter's data set. This
>   can be useful for drawing dividers between items, highlights, visual
>   grouping boundaries and more.
>
> All ItemDecorations are drawn in the order they were added, before the
>   item views (in `onDraw()` and after the items (in `onDrawOver(Canvas,
>   RecyclerView, RecyclerView.State)`.

Vertical spacing ItemDecoration
Extend ItemDecoration, add custom constructor which takes space height as a parameter and override `getItemOffsets()`:

```
public class VerticalSpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int mVerticalSpaceHeight;

    public VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(int mVerticalSpaceHeight) {
        this.mVerticalSpaceHeight = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
            RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.bottom = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to insert space below the last item, add the following condition:

```
if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) !=
                              parent.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
            outRect.bottom = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
}
```

Note: you can also modify outRect.top, outRect.left and outRect.right properties for desired effect.

Divider ItemDecoration
Extend ItemDecoration and override `onDraw()`:

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{android.R.attr.listDivider};

    private Drawable mDivider;

    /**
     * Default divider will be used
     */
    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context) {
        final TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
        mDivider = styledAttributes.getDrawable(0);
        styledAttributes.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Custom divider will be used
     */
    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int resId) {
        mDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
        int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

        int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

You can either call the first constructor that uses the default Android divider attributes, or the second one that uses your own drawable, for example drawable/divider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
            android:height="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ff992900" />
</shape>
```

Note: if you want the divider to be drawn over your items, override `onDrawOver()` instead.

### Usage

To use your new class add VerticalSpaceItemDecoration or DividerSpaceItemDecoration to RecyclerView, for example in your fragment's `onCreateView()`:

```
private static final int VERTICAL_ITEM_SPACE = 48;
private RecyclerView mUiRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

    mUiRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_home_recycler_view);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mUiRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);

    //add ItemDecoration
    mUiRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(VERTICAL_ITEM_SPACE));
    //or
    mUiRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity());
    //or
    mUiRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), R.drawable.divider));

    mUiRecyclerView.setAdapter(...);

    return rootView;
}
```

There's also Lucas Rocha's library which is supposed to simplify the item decoration process. Haven't tried it though.

Among its features are:

A collection of stock item decorations including:

- Item spacing Horizontal/vertical dividers.
- List item

Comment: I don't think you read the question correctly. ItemDecoration is not needed.

Comment: Actual this was my issue since everything was white it looked like one giant card, but when i set the background to black and they showed up. I didn't add your divider i found a simplified on and it is working great. Thank You!

Comment: Ahh, the white on white background. From your description I understood as all the information was being overwritten which is my mistake. Next time try applying a border to your `cardview` so that you can see your views properly. `ItemDecoration` is great for spacing between views but it is not mandatory.

Comment: I will keep that in mind and we may switch to that. but luckily that is the front ends job to make that decision so ill let her do it lol

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enclose your cardview with linearLayout and set up a padding for your linearLayout ( inner or outer ). But somehow even I devided it, I have no shadow around, so I added margin to outer linearLayout. Now it looks fine, but really odd, because even in official documentation, nothing about additional parameters and it works fine anyway.

Comment: I totally forward to add a margin around the CardView and it worked after setting a Margin to the CardView